# Airflow Workers starving for queued tasks

Tags: celery, airflow, amazon-sqs, worker, celery-task

I am using Airflow (1.10.3) with AWS RDS Postgres as metaStore and celery_backend, SQS as queue service and CeleryExecutor. I have 1 master machine running airflow webserver and scheduler service, and a 1 worker machine.

Airflow worker is always starving for more tasks (queued) with lot of unused resources (CPU and RAM, with usage always below 20%). I've observed worker pick up tasks in batches, for eg: If there are 10 tasks in queue and 2 running tasks, then it will wait for 2 tasks to complete before picking next batch of tasks from the queue.

Parallelism setting in airflow.cfg in Worker instances.
    `parallelism = 32` .
      `dag_concurrency = 32`.
     `non_pooled_task_slot_count = 128`.
    `max_active_runs_per_dag = 32`.
    `max_threads = 2`   (no issues in scheduler though, as tasks are queued immediately)

One important thing to point out in my implementation - Airflow task is not a single process task, and individual Task further spawns multiple processes (3-5). Though even after considering process counts, my airflow worker never reaches full parallelism.

Any suggestion to -
a). Is there a way to fully utilise parallel execution of tasks on an airflow worker? Or if there's some more info that I am missing while setting up Airflow.
b). Above mentioned parallelism settings are configured at airflow task as atomic-unit, or number of threads/processes that task spawns?

Thanks!

Comment: Celery doesn't yet completely support SQS FIFO queues which was causing above problem of worker not picking up tasks as it waits for jobs in flight to complete first before picking subsequent jobs. Moving to SQS normal queues solved my problem.